# Trim inside the Scalar UDF with stuff sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have a Tabled Valued function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFareBasisDetails](@BookingID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ','+REPLACE(PriceDetails.query(N'data(/FareInfo/Price/AB/PQ)').value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),' ',',')
    FROM [Traveler] [T]
    WHERE [T].BookingID=@BookingID
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') AS FarePriceBasis;
```

To get the value of FarePriceBasis I am using this function inside a stored procedure applying join with GetFareBasisDetails. Code chunk inside the sp is

Since I am getting the extra commas in my result , I'm trimming it inside the sp.

```
CASE 
            WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(REPLACE([FB].FarePriceBasis,',,',',')),1) = ',' THEN 
                LEFT(REPLACE([FB].FarePriceBasis,',,',','), LEN(REPLACE([FB].FarePriceBasis,',,',',')) - 1)
            ELSE REPLACE([FB].FarePriceBasis,',,',',') END [FarePriceBasis]
```

I want to move the trim logic inside the function.
i.e inside the sp , I can only use [FB].FarePriceBasis.
All the trimming logic should be moved inside function GetFareBasisDetails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy : Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Do you have any sample data and schema to highlight the problem?

Comment: @Steve : I just have to optimize it,  move the trim logic inside the UDF.
So that inside the SP I can only do [FB].FarePriceBasis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I must be missing something as you can just move your case statement inside of the function. Its not pretty and there is undoubtedly a better solution, but you can just do this.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFareBasisDetails](@BookingID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(REPLACE([FB].FarePriceBasis,',,',',')),1) = ',' 
              THEN LEFT(REPLACE([FB].FarePriceBasis,',,',','), LEN(REPLACE([FB].FarePriceBasis,',,',',')) - 1)
              ELSE REPLACE([FB].FarePriceBasis,',,',',') END [FarePriceBasis]
FROM  ( SELECT STUFF(
              (
                  SELECT  ','+REPLACE(PriceDetail,' ',',')
                  FROM    [Traveler] [T]
                  WHERE   [T].BookingID=@BookingID
                  FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '') AS FarePriceBasis
      ) FB
GO
```